# Elasticsearch programmatic configuration

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am working on a big data project that utilizes elasticsearch for handling the bulk of the data storage and searching capability. More specifically, we use the Java API to perform a lot of the indexing and searching operations. Part of the way the application has been designed is that when the application 'comes alive' so to speak, there is a check run against the elasticsearch cluster to make sure that all of the indices exist, and if they don't, they are created with settings/mappings that are defined in configuration files.

I see that as a bad approach, and I wanted to find out if my thinking/approach is right. I see the actual creating of indices and all of the type mappings as analogous to how you would perform table creations and setting up constraints in a relational database world, not something traditionally done programatically. I understand that you don't HAVE to explicitly setup mappings for the types you are going to save beforehand, since elasticsearch will give it a best guess for the mapping, but I would think you would want to do the legwork of getting all of the indices and mappings setup beforehand, and not have any sort of mappings and indices initialization done in code. Thoughts? I haven't been working with ES very long, still learning, but that just seems off to me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is sensible to plan your mapping types, as it's not possible to alter the type of a mapping field after you have stored data (without reindexing all your data). This is a particular problem if you have text fields that you will want to exactly match. By default elasticsearch will index your string fields by analysing those strings, and decomposing them into structures that can be easily matched by fuzzy searching. However this means that it's often not possible to match that string exactly.

For example if your mapping contains a field that contains email addresses, it will by default be analysed when it is stored. This can be altered by setting the mapping type to the following:

```
{
  "type":"string",
  "index":"not_analyzed"
}
```

The most important thing here is that, if you don't set this up before you start storing data in it, then you can't change it.